# When a two-generated ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ is the unit ideal or principal?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I am trying to figure out when the ideal $(a_1+b_1\sqrt{-3},a_2+b_2\sqrt{-3}) $ is the unit ideal or principal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do so directly as follows: Let $x+y\sqrt{-3} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. Multiply $a_1+b_1\sqrt{-3}$ by this number and set it equal to $a_2+b_2\sqrt{-3}$, then solve this system for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a_1$ and $b_1$. When can this system be solved and what happens when it can (principal ideal case)? When can this system not be solved (unit case)?

Comment: Ok that helped me out a bit, I see that if it is a Principal ideal then the generator should divide both $a_1+b_1\sqrt{-3}$ and $a_2+b_2\sqrt{-3}$ but I can’t see why what you said is true? Can you clear that out?

Comment: If the system can be solved (in integers!), that means $a_1+b_1\sqrt{-3}$ and $a_2+b_2\sqrt{-3}$ are "dependent" so to say. Finally, if the system is not solvable (in integers!), the set $\{a_1+b_1\sqrt{-3}, a_2+b_2\sqrt{-3} \}$ has "dimension 2" over $\mathbb{Z}$. And since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ is a Z-module with two generators, the ideal must be principal.

Comment: the second case did you mean the ideal is the unit ideal?. Because in the first case if they are dependent then one will generate the other hence it is Principal , so all ideals are Principal?

Comment: Sorry yes, the last sentence should read that the ideal is unit.